# Pink rigid board over existing VB and batt insulation?

Tags: insulation, kitchens

Replacing drywall on a north interior kitchen wall.  I am down the studs, tuck taped the VB over existing pink batts where needed, my questions can I install pink rigid board right over the VB and the 1/2" drywall with out issues?

So to recap for my understanding:  what i see on my north facing wall is pink batt insulation, VB with tuck tape and now  installing pink rigid boards over the VB (all i will see is rigid board and tuck tape on joints and then 1/2" drywall, and then kitchen cupboards.

Is there an issue doing this?

Comment: Longer screws needed for drywall and cabinets.  Compression of ridge board might lead to long term mudding defects.  Would mark stud locations on floor and ceiling.  Might not be needed if 2x6 studs, depending on your weather and other details.  More insulation is usually nicer, but comes with a cost/benefit ratio.

Comment: crip659, yes 4-5 screws will be needed now.  stud locations are marked as mention, great tip, ty!  Mudding defect might happen ig, but all mud is covered by cabinets and counterop, exposed area has no seams to be mudded and will eventually have a backsplash